# Firebase Messaging won't call BackgroundHandler on iOS (11.4.1)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying for few days now but I can't figure it out. The Firebase Messaging plugin just won't call the function that was set in `onBackgroundMessage`, not even when the application is in the background (and not terminated). I've tried this in debug and release builds, but nothing.

I'm trying to send the notifications via `flutter_local_notifications` but I don't think it matters as the callback doesn't even called.

I know for sure that my app is connected to Firebase because *it does* get notifications in `onMessage`.

The things I have done:

**1)** Connecting the app through the Firebase console, adding `GoogleService-Info` to the app.

**2)** Uploading to the Firebase console the APNs auth key.

**3)** Adding this function to my app as a **top-level** function:

```
  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // Not called in background\terminated state
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  ...
  }
```

and in the main():

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

**4)** Adding the following line to the AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
   }
  
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

}
```

**5)** Making sure my app has push notifications and background modes enabled (in **all** builds):

[image]

**6)** Giving the app notifications permissions:
[image]

**7)** Sending the notification as follows (*without* the notification tag, only the data tag) using the **node.js admin SDK**:

```
let message = {
    apns: {
        headers: {
            'apns-priority': '5',
        },
        payload: {
          aps: {
            contentAvailable: true
          },
        },
      },
    android: {
        priority: 'normal',
    },
    
    data: {
        title: "Test",
        message: "Test",
        url: "https://www.google.com/"
    },
    topic: topic
};
```

---

Debugging using the Console app on Mac brings the following result:

```
default 20:48:06.069282+0300    SpringBoard Received incoming message on topic com.matkonit at priority 5
default 20:48:06.082948+0300    SpringBoard [com.matkonit] Received remote notification request 3823-43DB [ waking: 0, hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 pushType: Background]
default 20:48:06.083005+0300    SpringBoard [com.matkonit] Process delivery of push notification 3823-43DB
```

So the notification *does* received by the OS and yet the Firebase handler is not called.

---

I have also tried countless solutions that were suggested on other StackOverlow posts but nothing helped...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: notification tag is required for iOS. you have to pass the title and body in the notification payload.

Comment: @ChiragKalsariya This is not true, see the example here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Comment: Try adding a notification key with title and body in your payload.

Comment: Commenting for future readers, Background notifications are not recommended when the iOS app is in terminated state. It will only work when the app is in paused state (in the background).

Answer (score 1):

I have the following firebase version and it works for me in debug mode
so please double check this steps:

1. Ensure you add background and remote notification capabilities from xcode
2. Don't use firebase console to test background notification as it won't work
3. build a small server or use postman to send notification , you can find that in firebase console docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#node.js
   or use this repo https://github.com/SHAHIDNX/NODEJS_pushnotifications
4. Send a silent notification

> {
> "to": "fcm_token",
> "data": {
> "clear_data": true
> },
> "content_available": true,
> "apns-priority": 5
> };
> notitce the different in content available

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting 'content-available': 1 from the node JS code did the trick. Code sample here.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#2980040

```
const message = {
             apns: {
                  payload: {
                     aps: {
                         'content-available': 1
                     }
                  }
             },
             data: {foo:'foo'},
             notification:{
                title: title,
                body: text
             },
             token: pushToken,
                                
          };
```

Answer (score -1):

In the app delegate have you tried checking if launchOptions contains "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey". Once I was not receiving notifications in my app because it was being attached in the launchOptions so I would have to check and handle them there. Not sure if it will help but its an edge case.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionsremotenotificationkey

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

- You need to look at the initialization of **FirebaseMessaging** Instance.
  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/
- Once you received the notification you will get that message in **_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler** see attached screenshot for the sample code.[image: Firebase Messaging Configuration]

Comment: How does it different from my code?